# Old Type C Schengen expires after type D

Tags: visa, france, indian-citizens

I have just moved to France with a 'Blue Card' work permit with my son and wife. We have type D visas (3 months to begin with) running out this week and have already applied for our first carte de séjour. As of right now, we have the receipts for our carte, which allow us to travel within the EU freely.

Now here's the problem: I have a trip planned to Dubai (Turkish airlines via Istanbul) during the time when I don't have the carte de séjour. I have been granted a temporary extended visa for my professional visits, but that doesn't extend to my wife.

My wife, however, has an overlapping Schengen type C visa, that was granted prior to the type D and expires long after the type D.

In short, my question is: can my wife come into France on the type C Schengen?

Clarifications:

- Both my wife and I have applied for our first carte de séjour. We
  have receipts which act as proxy visas within the EU, but not to
  enter the EU (for your first Carte DS). Application for my son can
  only be done once we get ours because he is 7 months old

  None of us have carte de séjour yet. I have been given an extended
  'return visa' which is given under exceptional circumstances such as
  medical emergencies or for professional reasons. I was able to get a
  letter from my employer to prove professional reasons. My wife
  doesn't have this return visa.

  My son doesn't need the visa because, as a minor, once he has a
  document called the 'DECM' which allows him to travel into the EU.

  My wife has a Schengen which should still be active. It was issued in
  Sep'15 up to Sep'16. We got our type D visa from May 16 to Aug 16.

Comment: The receipt for your application for your carte de sejour should be all you all need to get back into France. But I'm not 100% sure, so I don't want to put it as an answer.
However I think that the schengen visa is for a visit, rather than for living. You're better off travelling on that and re-entering with your receipt for your carte de sejour.